# Does my Linux kernel and NIC driver support NIC RX timestamps?

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, timestamp, network-programming

I want to get NIC RX timestamps. This example shows how to obtain them:

https://github.com/majek/openonload/blob/master/src/tests/onload/hwtimestamping/rx_timestamping.c

It contains the below function. Upon running I get an error message output.

```
static void do_ioctl(struct configuration* cfg, int sock)
{
#ifdef SIOCSHWTSTAMP
  struct ifreq ifr;
  struct hwtstamp_config hwc;
#endif

  if( cfg->cfg_ioctl == NULL )
    return;

#ifdef SIOCSHWTSTAMP
  bzero(&ifr, sizeof(ifr));
  snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "%s", cfg->cfg_ioctl);

  /* Standard kernel ioctl options */
  hwc.flags = 0;
  hwc.tx_type = 0;
  hwc.rx_filter = HWTSTAMP_FILTER_ALL;

  ifr.ifr_data = (char*)&hwc;

  TRY( ioctl(sock, SIOCSHWTSTAMP, &ifr) );
  return;
#else
  (void) sock;
  printf("SIOCHWTSTAMP ioctl not supported on this kernel.\n");     // I get this output
  exit(-ENOTSUP);
  return;
#endif
}
```

However, when I run the code I get:

> SIOCHWTSTAMP ioctl not supported on this kernel

By "kernel", does it mean the NIC driver, or the OS kernel?

I will be switching to use a Solarflare NIC soon and I am unsure whether this will fix the problem, or if the problem is with my Linux kernel?

If I hack it and `#define SIOCHWTSTAMP` myself I get compile errors not recognizing `struct ifreq` and `struct hwtstamp_config`

Comment: It's obvious that you're getting this error because that specific branch of the code is compiled and run (the one where `SIOCSHWTSTAMP` is not defined). I suspect that this is not the only place in the code (not the only source file) where the compilation depends on that definition.

Comment: My research shows that this ioctl has appeared in Linux kernel 2.6.30. Unless you're using an earlier kernel version to compile this for, you should have this defined in the kernel sources. Perhaps it's a matter of finding and including the right header file.

Comment: @Aleksey would you happen to know which header in the link is the one which relates to this include? netdb.h, sys/types.h, sys/socket.h, sys/ioctl.h, net/if.h

Comment: knowing your kernel version and environment/distribution version would help.
It looks like the file in question is `<linux/sockios.h>` in kernel 2.6.30. It's `<uapi/linux/sockios.h>` starting with kernel 3.7. This header file is included in `<linux/socket.h>` in a heavily backported kernel 3.10 that I have at hand (note the difference: `linux/` here vs `sys/` in your sample) Perhaps a change from `sys` to `linux` would help you. Just be careful to do that wherever there's a dependency on this definition. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Aleksey We're using 3.10.0-957.27.2 so I should use the <sys/sockios.h>?

Comment: I just have taken a closer look at the full sources at the link in your question. It's a little convoluted. Effectively, this depends on definition (or not) of `NO_KERNEL_TS_INCLUDE` which, in turn, depends on presence of two header files as clearly stated in the Makefile. The files are not there where it's thought they have to be. As unusual as it sounds, it appears that these two files are provided by the package `linux-libc-devel` on my system. Please try to install this package and see if this is indeed the solution. Previously I thought that it's a kernel code which was not the case.

Comment: @Aleksey will do. What is the easiest way to check I have everything which is required? I thought hardware timestamping was part of the Standard Linux recvmsg API?

Comment: Just check and see that these two header files are present after you install the package. The correct name for it is `linux-libc-dev` (sorry for the typo).